# ability to remember which camera roll photos should not be displayed when reopening app (ios)

Tags: ios, iphone, alassetslibrary, alasset, photolibrary

In my application the user can display the camera roll photos and there is an option to not show/display a particular image next time. My question: is there any flag, EXIF or metadata info to let the application not display the flagged images when the user opens the app again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remember the URL of the unwanted images and then hide the images with that URL.

`NSURL *url = asset.defaultRepresentation.url`